# Can I use java lambda expression in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda

I come from java, I am used to java lambdas, now I am working in a kotlin project and I see that there are other kind of lambdas, since I prefer java syntax (I also read they are better in performance)

> Can I still use java lambdas in kotlin?

I try to do it but it doesn´t compile:

[image]

Comment: No, you cannot. Kotlin is not Java.

Comment: kotlin is supposed 100% compatible with Java, it looks like there are some differences between them

Comment: kotlin has it's own lambda methodology. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html

Comment: Sure you can. Just write your lambda in a .java file, then reference it from Kotlin. (if it wasn't obvious, don't actually do this)

Comment: Cool, as Jorn says I can still use it in .java files and they are 100% compatible, Thank you!

Comment: I hope someone will review that code

Comment: "100% compatible with Java" does not mean that you can use Java syntax while programming in Kotlin. It means that Kotlin code can interoperate with Java code, so you can call code that was written in Java (in a Java source file, compiled with the Java compiler) without problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntactically, no. In Kotlin, you can only write lambdas in the Kotlin way, i.e.

```
{ p1, p2, p3 -> ... }
```

That doesn't mean that you can't pass Kotlin lambdas to Java APIs accepting a functional interface though. This is totally possible.

After all, Kotlin and Java are two different languages and have different syntaxes.

```
// Stream.map is a Java API, but it can take a "Kotlin lambda" just fine
ids.stream().map { anId -> anId + 1 }
```

However, since you mention that Java lambdas are "better in performance" (assuming you mean that they are compiled to `invokedynamic` calls), it should be noted that Kotlin lambdas do this too since Kotlin 1.5, under certain circumstances, as discussed [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew15.html#sam-adapters-via-invokedynamic):

> Kotlin 1.5.0 now uses dynamic invocations (`invokedynamic`) for
> compiling SAM (Single Abstract Method) conversions:
>
> - Over any expression if the SAM type is a Java interface
> - Over lambda if the SAM type is a Kotlin functional interface

So the `Stream.map` call above would be compiled using `invokedynamic`, just like a Java lambda would, because it is a conversion to the Java interface `java.util.function.Function`. On the other hand, a regular Kotlin lambda would be compiled to an anonymous inner class.